# In dataframes created by a loop, add suffix to columns that increases with iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am creating multiple dataframes numbered from 1 to n through a loop.
The first thing I do for this, is create a dictionary:

```
dict_of_df = {}
```

then runs the loop:

```
for i in range(1, n+1): 
    ... import data
    ... manipulate data
    ... create a dataframe corresponding to the "i" value of the loop
    dict_of_df["df_{}".format(i)] = _my_last_manipulated_data_
```

This creates a dictionary of dataframes named `df_1`,`df_2`...`df_n`, and I can access each of them outside the loop for further treatment using:

```
df_1 = dict_of_df["df_1"]
df_2 = dict_of_df["df_2"]
...
etc
```

The problem is that the data I import are very similar, and all the dataframes resulting from the loop, `df_1`, `df_2`, ... `df_n`, have the same number of columns sharing the same names; that is to say, all the `df_i` have the 4 columns names `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`.

What could I do inside my loop in order to have names `A_1`,`B_1`,`C_1`,`D_1` when `df_1` is created, then `A_2`,`B_2`,`C_2`,`D_2` when `df_2` is created, and so on...?

I guess the last line of the loop, `dict_of_df["df_{}".format(i)] = ...` should be modified, but I don't see in what way. I thought to introduce `enumerate` somewhere, but I don't know in what form exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `add_suffix` method. So use the line below in the last line of your loop:

```
dict_of_df["df_{}".format(i)] = _my_last_manipulated_data_.add_suffix(f'_{i}')
```